# Emacs on Minix 3?

Tags: software-installation, emacs, minix

Has anybody managed to install Emacs on Minix 3? Emacs was available on earlier versions of Minix. I am OK with an earlier version of Emacs if necessary. I don't find Zile, mg or Elle adequate and would prefer the full version of Emacs, even if it is an old version. I don't need a GUI version `emacs-nox` is OK, I will be running it from the command line anyway.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/tcort/emacs-minix-port?